# Is Z/pZ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If p is a prime number, is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}$/p$\mathbb{Z}$ a field? How to show it?

I take an arbitrary nonzero element a + p$\mathbb{Z}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$/p$\mathbb{Z}$. Need to show it has a unit. It suffices to show that there exists b + p$\mathbb{Z}$ such that (a + p$\mathbb{Z}$ )(b + p$\mathbb{Z}$ ) = 1 + p$\mathbb{Z}$ , i.e. ab + p$\mathbb{Z}$ = 1 + p$\mathbb{Z}$ or ab $-$ 1 $\in$ p$\mathbb{Z}$. But how can we prove that there exists such an integer b?  I need to set b = $\frac{np + 1}{a}$ for some integer n. But it seems difficult to guarantee b is an integer.

Comment: As you note, it is enough to show that $ab - 1 \in p\mathbb{Z}$. The latter is true iff there exists some integer $n$ with $ab + np = 1$. Now, $\gcd(a,p) = 1$. Do you know of a theorem that lets you proceed?

Comment: wait, why can we have gcd(a,p) = 1? And I am not sure what theorem can let me proceed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity